# What percentage of facial basal cell carcinomas (BCC) are superficial or infiltrative?

Tags: dermatology, face, basal-cell-carcinoma

I read [here](https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/276624-workup#c8) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201116000410/https://emedicine.medscape.com/article/276624-workup)):

- Superficial basal cell carcinoma: Approximately 10-15% of all BCCs are of this type. This is the most common pattern seen in BCCs of the shoulder.
- The solid (nodular) type accounts for approximately 70% of all cases.
- Infiltrative basal cell carcinoma: This type of BCC accounts for 10% of BCCs.

However "This is the most common pattern seen in BCCs of the shoulder." seems to
indicate that the percentage of a given BCC types depends on its location (face, neck, extremities, trunk, etc.).

What percentage of facial basal cell carcinomas (BCC) are superficial or infiltrative? (I'm looking for 2 percentages: 1 for superficial and 1 for infiltrative)